# React router - history.push to a specific section of page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React router, can I use history.push to change the page, and also go to a specific section/anchor on the new page? For example:

```
 history.push('/home#section1');
```

In my home page I have this:

```
  <div class='back  backCard backCardFour ' id='section1'>
                    <div>
                        Then please don't hesitate to contact us, you can
                        use "Send us your thoughts that it's located on the
                        top of the page and ask us everything or give some
                        suggestions to improve our work
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I'd say you will have to redirect with props, but maybe there's a better way..

Comment: It worked fine but now i wanna go to a specific section and i don't know how can i do it

Answer (score 2):

React Router itself doesn't support anchors.

You can use something like [React Router Hash Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with props, eg.:

```
history.push('/home', 'section1');
```

And then inside your '/home' component check for these 'redirect' props. If there is one, call a `scrollIntoView` function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const view = this.props.location.state;
    const section1 = document.getElementById('section1');

    if (view) {
        section1.scrollIntoView();
    }
}
```